# Cookie not being deleted after session closed

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I'm using cookies that should be deleted after user closes the page, but they're not. This is how I set cookies with JS

```
document.cookie="status=false";
```

I can see the cookie in console and after I close browser and open it again and go to my webpage there's still cookie `status=false` any idea why?

Comment: If none of the answers work for you: The cookie _should_ be deleted, from the info you provided. There seems to be something else that goes wrong. Please create a new blank HTML page, and try to reproduce the problem with the smallest amout of (unnecessary) code.Then, add it to your question so we can play with it and find what's wrong.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I created the "fresh" page only with one cookie and when I create it in dev tools it says Duration:Sesion, and after I close tab and open the page in new there's still that cookie. Here's the code http://pastie.org/10065425

Comment: That's weird, I copy-pasted your code, put it on a server, visited it with Firefox, set the cookie successfully, closed the browser, reopened it, went to the page, looked for the cookie: gone. I then did the same with Chrome. Same result. What browser are you using?

Comment: Weird lol, I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this "trick", I don't know why I can't get cookies to work

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    document.cookie="status=false";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.cookie = ...` [sets individual cookie values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), it does not set "the entire cookie" to the string you passed, so setting "status=false" simply binds or updates the "status" value, irrespective of whatever else is in the cookie:

```
document.cookie = "cow=bell";
document.cookie = "cat=lol";
// cookie is now "cow=bell&cat=lol", not just "cat=lol"
```

If you want to delete the entire cookie, set its expiration time to "in the past" and the browser will do the cleanup for you.

(As pointed out in a comment, if you never set an expiration timestamp for your cookie, it'l expire when the page session ends, e.g. you close the tab/browser)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually doing this today. A great reference is the [Mozilla cookie documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) if you create a js with their `var docCookies` code then using the functions provided like `docCookies.setItem() docCookies.setItem() docCookies.getItem()` or `docCookies.removeItem()` work incredible well.